# Implementing lasso select

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

here's what we have today:
* NxM grid of points in 3D
* we draw these using legacy opengl calls.
* we have a rubberband select and single point selection, using selection buffer.

Today we can use CTRL to select parts of what we want to select until we have the selection we want. but it is getting very annoying if you have a 200x500 grid and want to select a circle, star or anythingn that is not a rectangle.

I've tried to find any info on how to create a lasso selection, some people uses unique colors for each object and then uses readpixel to see what was sselected. We can't use this because all of our points needs to be the same color.

Comment: `some people uses unique colors for each object and then uses readpixel to see what was sselected. We can't use this because all of our points needs to be the same color.` well you only need to do that for one frame when you make the selection and you can draw it offscreen, so that argument doesn't fly.

Comment: Can you draw the unique colors offscreen while drawing the lasso? What is the proper way of doing that? Still haven't found any proper help on that subject. I'm thinking draw every four/five frame offscreen to see if a new point has been selected with the mouse ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a pretty good illustrated tutorial on color picking at Lighthouse3D.com:

http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/picking/index.php?color1

Its quite fast & I have implemented this technique in apps with millions of polygons. Way faster than bounding boxes since you only check what's under the cursor (or lasso region). Also, it's compatible with OpenGL ES as the feedback buffer selection is on its way out.

Comment: Thnk you for your reply :) One thing I dont get from the tutorial: How do I switch between rendering the front and back buffer? And is it possible to render them at the same time? I'm thinking live select. The user holds down CTRL and as the mousepointer intersects with a point it selects it.

Comment: I just found out how to differ between front and back buffer, thanks to your link I now have a working unique color picking. Thank you very much :)